# Easy way to recreate windows phone system app animations?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, animation

I really like the way the system applications (People, messages, mail, music+video, etc) are animated on transitions. So in my app, I'd like to use the same style so that it blends in better with the whole phone (plus they just look pretty). I've been poking around in the silverlight toolkit for a while trying to find preset animations I could use to do this, but I'm having trouble finding the same ones.

More specifically, I'm having trouble finding the equivalent to the 'slide/ pivot' animation you can see when you select a contact from your contact list (and in a hundred other places).

Are these animations available somewhere as a preset? Or do I have to try to make them myself by using a storyboard?

I don't know that much about silverlight animations, so I'm trying to avoid having to learn, but if I really have to so be it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: well it's for a project that's being developed on all 3 major phone platforms, so we're getting maximum spread. plus the wp7 version is the best for demos

Comment: Wp7 rocks, fast development and superior dev tools.  It's very pleasant, not a bother at all.

Comment: Plus, you can be a bigger fish, because the marketplace is a smaller pond-- though that's changing very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get these transitions from the Silverlight Toolkit.  http://silverlight.codeplex.com

Also, here's a quick guide for implementing them:  http://codifying.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/wp7-how-to-create-beautiful-page-transition-in-5-minutes/

Comment: Does it have that one I was talking about? when you select an item from a listview and it sort of slides to the right and pivots a bit? I can't seem to find it

Comment: ok, I just spent 5 minutes watching the contacts pivot ("how'd you spend your Saturday?"). I don't think there's anything exactly like this.  It looks like a combination of one style transition out, and another on transition in.  Add to that a sort of rotation transform to the list item and to the title on the page, and I have to say that I haven't seen anything exactly like that.  Generally, I use pivot out and slide-up back in.

Comment: Haha, yeah I think I might just do that too then. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: hate to ask again, but what class is pivot out contained in? I'm having trouble finding it

Comment: It should all be in the Silverlight Toolkit.  `<toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>`

Comment: Ah I see what you meant by pivot now, I thought it was a different animation I hadn't seen yet. Thanks!